# What are NsightEclipse.xml files useful for?

Tags: cuda, nsight

What are the NsightEclipse.xml files provided with the CUDA samples? What are they useful for?

I did not manage to import them in NSight-Eclipse. They seem to contain project information, but not enough for a build.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, NsightEclipse.xml is the project file for cuda sample.

Actually you don't need to worry about what it is if you want to import the cuda sample, you can follow these steps to import the cuda samples into nsight.

1. New CUDA c++ project
2. Choose Import CUDA Sample
3. Choose which sample you want to import, then finish.

Comment: Does it mean NsightEclipse.xml is useless? Actually when I load the NsightEclipse.xml project in Nsight, not all the includes are listed and I hence get compilation errors...

Answer (score 1):

Those files are used to generate Nsight projects when importing the sample as @harryz outlined.

Project files in Eclipse are platform and machine dependent so it was easier to generate on the spot - but we still needed some information that is now stored in those XMLs.